# Is it possible to use wildcards in sbt IO.copy command

Tags: sbt

I have defined an sbt task to copy files from one directory to another:

```
val inDir = crossTarget.value / "inFolder
val outDir = file("jvm/target/outFolder")
val files = Seq("scrip1.js", "script2.js").map { p =>   (inDir / p, outDir / p) }
IO.copy(files, overwrite = true, preserveLastModified = false, preserveExecutable = false)
```

Is it possible to modify this just to copy all files with a *.js* extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
val files = (inDir * "*.js").pair(f => outDir / f.name).get
```

See https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/io/PathFinder.html